# Refer to Dynamic Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Each day I open a file with today's date in the file name to get data.

I put the data into another workbook with today's date in the file name.

I've gotten to the point where I have Excel open the first file based on the current date, but I'm having trouble switching between both workbooks since the file name changes each day.

In one of the workbooks I have what the name of the file will be today e.g. Reporting Status_23-Nov-2018, and the formula I wrote will update the name to be Reporting Status_24-Nov-2018 tomorrow. I was trying to define a variable to be the cell value with the report name so that I could say `VariableName.activate`. I would do the same thing for the second workbook.

I've got the following code:

```
Dim BLREOD as workbook
Dim Midday as workbook
. 
. 
. 
BLREOD = activeworkbook.sheets("sheet name").range("X4").Value
Midday = activeworkbook.sheets("sheet name").range("X7").Value
```

Where `X4` and `X7` have the name of the file for today.

This doesn't work and I haven't been able to find anything on declaring a workbook variable as a cell value and then activating that variable's workbook.

Comment: Try `Set BLREOD = workbooks(activeworkbook.sheets("sheet name").range("X4").Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could open each workbook directly with `Workbooks.Open` and use the 2 references to interact with them:

```
Sub OpenWorkbooks()
    Dim BLREOD As Workbook
    Dim Midday As Workbook

    Dim shParams As Worksheet
    Set shParams = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name")

    Dim todayBLREODWBName As String, todayMiddayWBName As String
    todayBLREODWBName = shParams.Range("X4").Value
    todayMiddayWBName = shParams.Range("X7").Value

    Set BLREOD = Workbooks.Open(todayBLREODWBName)
    Set Midday = Workbooks.Open(todayMiddayWBName)

    Midday.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Value = BLREOD.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```